# Is regular following language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

I try to prove that the language $L$ is not regular:
$$
  L = \{w\in(a+b)^*:\#_a(u)>2009\#_b(u)\ \text{for every nonempty prefix u of word w} \}
$$
Note: $\#_a(u)$ means the number of symbols $a$ in the word $u$.

Let $p$ let be the length in pumping lemma. Let $w=(a^{2009p}ab^{p})^*\in L$
[image]

Let according to lemma $w=xyz$, where $|y|>0, |xy|\le p$.
And now, look at $s'=xy^0z$. Since $y=aa...aa$ and $ 1\le|y|\le p$,
the word $s'$ has no more than $2009p$ symbols $a$ in some prefix.
Therefore $s'\notin L$ - so the language is not regular (thanks to the pumping lemma).
What about this solution ?

Comment: Why did you use 2009?

Comment: Look again on my post (I edited)

Comment: Nobody Can help ?

Comment: The argument is correct.

Answer (score 5):

**Community answer to remove from unanswered**

The argument is correct

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Hi, I know this answer is not what stackexchange is for. But there are no way for me to not see again and again the same question in the unanswered questions except to answer the. (there are plenty of discussion in Meta about this situation but nothing that solve the problem). what do you sugest? (you voted to delete an other similar answer).